# Hosting many public facing sites single farm sharepoint-Architecture

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am planning to host different public facing websites on a single farm in SPS 2010.But I want the architecture to be like that when one site goes down or we are doing any maintenance on one site it should not affect other sites in SharePoint..I would like to know any suggestions on how should be the architecture for it...any good links where i can find this or any suggestions...right now i m having one application server 2 WFE....but that would turn into single point failure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Multi-Tenancy in SharePoint 2010](http://www.harbar.net/presentations/spevo/DD105%20Multi%20Tenancy.pdf) presentation - it's gives a good overview of the problem.